# How to clean elements in xml string

Tags: php, regex, xml, preg-replace

I have a xml, where  tags can have one,two or more spaces and periods(.) in elements.

```
the xml:
    $xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
 <xmldata>  
  <SalesHeader>  
      <DocType>Order</DocType>  
      <No>1002</No>  
      <SellToCustomerNo>CustNo</SellToCustomerNo>  
      <SellToCustomerName>Customer Name</SellToCustomerName>  
      <SellToCustomerName2 />   
      <SellToEmail>testemail@aol.com</SellToEmail>  
      <OrderDate>04/03/13</OrderDate>  
      <ExtDocNo />  
      <ShipToName>Customer Ship to</ShipToName>  
      <ShipToCountry />  
      <TaxLiable>No</TaxLiable>  
      <TaxAreaCode />  
      <RequestedDeliveryDate />  
      <Shipping Agent>UPS</Shipping Agent>  
      <Shipping Agent Service>Ground New</Shipping Agent Service>  
      <Tracking Numbers>123123212,1231231321</Tracking Numbers>  
      <SalesLine>  
        <ItemNo.>12-34343-23</ItemNo.>  
        <Description>Item Description</Description>  
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>  
        <UnitPrice>79.00</UnitPrice>  
      </SalesLine>  
      <SalesLine>  
        <ItemNo.>12-34343-23</ItemNo.>  
        <Description>Item Description</Description>  
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>  
        <UnitPrice>79.00</UnitPrice>  
      </SalesLine>  
  </SalesHeader>  
 </xmldata>';
```

my code:

```
preg_replace(array('/(<\/?)[. ]+(\w*)(\/?>)/','/(<\/?)(\w*)[. ]+(\/?>)/','/(<\/?)(\w*)[. ]+(\w*\/?>)/'),array('$1$2$3','$1$2$3','$1$2$3'),$xml);
```

I've achieved only delete using preg_match when there is one space or period, but I want is delete periods(.) and replace the spaces with underscore(_) even if there are several periods or/and spaces in tags and any position.

I want to get this:

```
change:
<ItemNo.>12-34343-23</ItemNo.> 
by:
<ItemNo>12-34343-23</ItemNo> 

change:
<Shipping Agent>UPS</Shipping Agent> 
by
<Shipping_Agent>UPS</Shipping_Agent> 

change:
<Shipping Agent Service>Ground New</Shipping Agent Service> 
by
<Shipping_Agent_Service>Ground New</Shipping_Agent_Service>
```

Comment: FYI - Those aren't attributes, they're elements.

Comment: May we ask how you end up with invalid XML in the first place? It's crazy not to be able to use SimpleXML or any other proper library....

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario I have to parse to use SimpleXMLElement()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I resolved the problem by my self, this is the code:

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
 <xmldata xmlns="http://some.uri.com">  
  <SalesHeader>  
      <DocType name="sample">Order</DocType>  
      <No>1002</No>  
      <SellToCustomerNo>CustNo</SellToCustomerNo>  
      <SellToCustomerName>Customer Name</SellToCustomerName>  
      <SellToCustomerName2 />   
      <SellToEmail>testemail@aol.com</SellToEmail>  
      <OrderDate>04/03/13</OrderDate>  
      <ExtDocNo />  
      <ShipToName>Customer Ship to</ShipToName>  
      <ShipToCountry />  
      <TaxLiable>No</TaxLiable>  
      <TaxAreaCode />  
      <RequestedDeliveryDate />  
      <Shipping Agent>UPS</Shipping Agent>  
      <Shipping Agent Service>Ground New</Shipping Agent Service>  
      <Tracking Numbers>123123212,1231231321</Tracking Numbers>  
      <SalesLine>  
        <ItemNo.>12-34343-23</ItemNo.>  
        <Description>Item Description</Description>  
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>  
        <UnitPrice>79.00</UnitPrice>  
      </SalesLine>  
      <SalesLine>  
        <ItemNo.>12-34343-23</ItemNo.>  
        <Description>Item Description</Description>  
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>  
        <UnitPrice>79.00</UnitPrice>  
      </SalesLine>  
  </SalesHeader>  
 </xmldata>';

function xmlcleaner($data){
    try{
        $xml_clean = preg_replace_callback('/(<\/?[^><]+\/?>)/',function($data){
            return preg_replace(array('/\./','/\s(?!\/|\>|\w+=\S+)/'),array('','_'),$data[0]);
        },$data['xml']);
        if(!empty($data['head'])){
            $xml_clean = preg_replace('/<\?.+\?>/','',$xml_clean);
            $xml_clean = $data['head'].$xml_clean;
        }
        //now work with SimpleXMLElement
        $result = new \SimpleXMLElement((string)$xml_clean);
        return $result;
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
$xml_clean = xmlcleaner(array(
    'xml'=>$xml,
    'head'=>'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
));
print('<pre>');
print_r($xml_clean);
```

Comment: While this does work on your sample input, be aware that it will cause problems if your XML ever contains attributes.  For example, try changing the first tag to `<xmldata xmlns="http://some.uri.com">`, which it will replace with `<xmldata_xmlns="http://someuricom">`.  If that's never a concern for you, great - but that's why I was steering away from the Regex-only solution.

Comment: thanks @Dan Field, you have right, but the xml that I receive only has elements, but I've improved the regex also to accept attributes

Answer (score 2):

I assume your XML text has a well-defined structure. In this case there are only several invalid element names and all of them are known in advance.

The best solution to your problem is to create a list of replacements (wrong value => correct value) and use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to fix your XML text before parsing it with [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) or [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php):

```
$replacements = array(
    '<Shipping Agent>'  => '<Shipping_Agent>',
    '</Shipping Agent>' => '</Shipping_Agent>',
    '<Shipping Agent Service>'  => '<Shipping_Agent_Service>',
    '</Shipping Agent Service>' => '</Shipping_Agent_Service>',
    '<Tracking Numbers>'  => '<Tracking_Numbers>',
    '</Tracking Numbers>' => '</Tracking_Numbers>',
    '<ItemNo.>'  => '<ItemNo>',
    '</ItemNo.>' => '</ItemNo>',
);

$xml = str_replace(array_keys($replacements), array_values($replacements), $xml);

$result = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

#### Why is this the best solution?

- It is clear for other programmers on the first glance what changes are operated on the input string.
- It doesn't leave any room for mistakes. If the format of the input string changes (new badly formatted element names appear), it is very easy to add the wrong open and close tags and their correct forms and the code runs without problems and without needing careful testing. Let's say a new invalid element name that breaks the rules of valid XML formatting in a different way appears in the input string. Changing the `regex`-es requires close attention and extensive testing.
- It runs much faster than your function `xmlcleaner()` because it uses a single call to `str_replace()` while `xmlcleaner()` calls `preg_replace()` multiple times; [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)  is slower than [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to begin with.

Comment: Agree agree with this approach of making a SPECIFIC solution if indeed the XML format is known and doesn't change.

Comment: This should work well because it's not actually going to try to fix things it can't (Such as tags that are supposed to have periods or spaces).

Comment: @DanField [XML element names](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name) are not allowed to contain space characters. They are, however, **explicitly** permitted to contain the dot character (`.`). I recommend using this approach because the code is shorter, faster and cleaner and, as you said, it doesn't "fix" what is not supposed to be fixed.

Comment: They're not allowed to have spaces, but if they have attributes there might be a space in what's matched as an element - i.e. `<root xmlns="blah">`.  There's further complexity in that an attribute value might have a space, like `<node attr="this is my value"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll have much luck coming up with a good regex for this.  Even if you could, the spaces in particular are worrysome.  Consider the following valid nodes:

```
<shipper name='baz' />
<shipper name='foo baz bang' />
<shipper name='foo.baz' />
<shipper.name />
```

Compared to nodes you want to correct:

```
<ship to name />
<ship. />
```

I think what you'd want to do is come up with a regex to match a tag, such as

```
$xmlParts = preg_split("/<[^>]+>/", $xml);
```

You could then iterate through `$xmlParts`.  If it matches that same regex, it's an XML tag, and you could do some validation on it: check to see if it spaces should be replaced with _ (because they're not to indicate an attribute name or value), and if .'s should be replaced completely (because they're not part of an attribute value).  After replacing invalid characters, append it to a new XML varaible.

If it doesn't match the regex, assume it's content and just append it.

With all of that said, it'd be a lot easier if you could get whatever's providing you with this "XML" to provide you with valid XML to begin with...

Comment: Hi, I don't want to compare, but that I want is parse for use SimpleXMLElement();

Comment: Right.  I'm saying you could use this idea to preprocess the string into valid XML.

Comment: Ahh ok, well invalid in his context anyway (he wants to get rid of the period).  I've updated the answer.